# replacing a sub string using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains sub strings like

```
           RTDEFINITION(55,4)         RTDEFINITION(45,2)
```

I need to replace every occurrence of this kind of string with another string:

```
          DEFRTE
```

using Python and regular expressions. Any ideas?
 thx

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific about what "this kind of string" means.

Comment: Do you want `RTDEFINITION(55,4)         RTDEFINITION(45,2)`  ie, the pair to be replaced or each instance of `RTDEFINITION(55,4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
import re

re.sub(r'RTDEFINITION\(\d+,\d+\)', 'DEFRTE', mystring)
```

Comment: it is just there are other occurrences like RTDEFINITION(44,3) in the text file